# is there a way to get my python selenium bot to start by itself at a certain time

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, bots

im trying to get this bot to launch by itself at a certain time. i am brand new to coding so please explain your answers more thoroughly. if i can program it that on a certain date and time it would start that would be amaizing.. if you see anything else in the code that can be fixed please let me know.. thanks [image: screenshot]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
start_time = time.time()

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# start action
# open page
driver.get("https://catalog.usmint.gov/andrew-jackson-presidential-silver-medal-S807.html?cgid=2020-product-schedule")
# maximize window
#driver.maximize_window()

# add to bag
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]')) #add to
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]").click()
# checkout
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a')) #checkout
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a').click()
# login
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]').send_keys("username")
# password
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]').send_keys("password")
# checkout as registered user
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span')) #checkout as
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span').click()
# credit card scroll
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]')) #credit card scroll
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]').click()
#cvv
        time.sleep(.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]').send_keys('987')
# continue to final review
        time.sleep(.5)
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]')) #continue to final
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_id("checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator").click()
# terms of use button
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span')) #terms of use
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]').send_keys("987")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_id("checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator").click()
        time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span').click()
# place order
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]')) #Place order
    )
        break
    except:
        driver.get(driver.current_url) # refresh
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]').click()
print("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
print("coin purchased")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install APSheduler API by:

```
pip install schedule
```

This is modified from their sample program:

````
import time

def main:
    #your program defined in a function main

schedule.every().day.at("#time").do(#yourFunction)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # wait one minute```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are tring to launch it in linux, you can use [crontab](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afiz). like this:

```sh
# open a cron table
$ crontab -e
# edit the table like, this means your python script while launch on the 3rd and 15th minutes of each hour
3,15 * * * * your_python_script
```

If you want to launch it in windows, you can use the [task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

[image]

[image]

create a basic task, set the time and your script path.

[image]